# Removing leading dots from find command output when used with -exec echo {} option

Tags: find

```
find . -type f -exec  echo {} \;
```

Using the above command, I want to get file names without leading "./" characters. So basically, I want to get:

```
filename
```

Instead of:

```
./filename
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: For files in sub-directories, do you just want `filename` or `path/to/sub/dir/filename` (without the leading `./`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find . -type f -exec  echo {} \;`

Default action of `find` is to print results. When not explicitly told, `find` defaults to searching current directory. Your command can be simplified to `find -type f`.

Why/when does this matter? Only when you run this command on a sufficiently large directory, you will start to see the performance difference. `-exec echo {} \;` will make your computer work needlessly more because it has to start an external process like `/bin/echo` to print the filenames. One instance of echo executable is run per file found by `find`.

To answer your question about removing `./`, a more efficient method would be to use `cut`. You know that the first two characters are always `./`. `cut -c3-` will only retain characters from position 3 and beyond.

```
> cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
> find -type f | cut -c3-
99pdftoopvp.conf
00kde.conf
65-khmer.conf
README
```

This fails to work as expected if your filenames contain new line character, but that is another whole new story.

Comment: The cut option is the only one that works on my Linux machine for multilevel outputs. Thanks!

Comment: The form that omits specifying a search path/paths (`find -type f`) is not currently POSIX compatible behavior. This fails with variants of find(1) that are not GNU find.

Comment: `cut`  cuts each line but there's nothing stopping a file path from containing newline characters.

Answer (score 66):

Use `*` instead of `.` and the leading `./` disappears.

```
find * -type f
```

Note that it's the shell that first expands that `*` to the sorted list of non-hidden (by default) files in the current working directory and passes them instead of `.` as separate arguments to `find`.  That has several implications  that should be noted:

- hidden files are omitted at the top level but not at deeper  levels (the ones  traversed by `find`).
- the list is sorted at the top level (generally a plus)
- you may run into the limit on the number of arguments that can be passed to command if the current working directory has a lot of file.
- That won't work if there are files named `!`, `(`, `)` or with a name starting with `-`, with possible nasty consequences if there's a file called `-delete` for instance.

Comment: works on macOS Catalina zsh

Comment: This is neat. It's worth mentioning that `*` is expanded by the shell to a list of all files that is then passed to `find`. Depending on the shell and its settings that listing may or may not contain files whose names start in a dot. That may be different from what `find` would do if it were given `.`. For bash you can use `find * .* -type f` to list all files.

Comment: @Hannes Don't use `.*` but `.[^.]* *`, else find will explore `..` See my answer for the full command. BTW, this is quite depressing to notice that this answer only repeats one of the commands I posted 3 years before, and yet this answer has twice more votes than mine despite it is incomplete (hidden files are omitted) and despite I warned such a construct should be avoided. Go figure... clearly, people prefer short answers, even if such answers fail in certain situations.

Comment: You are right. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: With this I get shellcheck issue [SC2012](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2012) - just imagine one of the files is named `-name`.

Comment: Lovely answer. Thank you!

Comment: This command fails if there are files beginning with - in the folder.

Comment: It fails if there are too many files for the shell to expand

Answer (score 38):

Assuming that you don't want the filename alone, but also the full relative path without the leading `./`, if you have GNU `find` you can use:

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n'
```

From find(1) man page:

> **`%P`** -  File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

Else, you can try one of these:

```
find . -type f -print | cut -d/ -f2-

find .[!.]* * -type f -print
```

You should avoid this last one (think of the excessively long command line if you have a lot of entries in your directory).

`-print` does the same thing as your `-exec echo {} \;` but is much better: no external process call so lower overhead and no undesirable side-effects with filenames beginning with a dash.

Comment: Using the `.[^.]*` syntax does not work in any (posix) shell that I am aware of.

Comment: @Juan From what I read, you know at least one shell that does not understand the `.[^.]*` syntax or that includes `.` and `..` in the resulting pathname expansion. Would you be kind enough to name it and explain what does not work? I do agree this is not strictly POSIX compliant and one should use `.[!.]*` instead, but I have used this syntax on many platforms for more than 30 years and never had a problem with it.

Comment: some shells where the `.[^.]*` syntax does not match strings that start with a dot followed by a non-dot: mksh r59, dash 0.5.10.2, ksh 2020.0.0, pdksh 5.2.14 - some cause the error: "find: .[^.]*: No such file or directory". However, it looks liks POSIX currently *does* specify bracket expressions as valid (and not optional) for pattern matching (see the 'Shell and Utilities' document, 'Pattern Matching Notation': https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). So the shells where it does not work appear to be deficient as far as POSIX is concerned.

Comment: Regarding the previous comment.  Interestingly, in the posix doc specified in the previous comment, section 2.13.1 explains that '!' can be used for the character class negation. And using '^' unquoted can produce "unspecified results".  If you do `ls -d .[^.]*` with dash, it only lists `..`, but `ls -d .[!.]*` lists dot files and not `.` nor `..`.  So dash does support bracket expressions, albeit a bit differently than bash.  It looks like dash doesn't support the ^ negation at all (which is not what posix is specifying as I read it).

Comment: It looks like using `.[!.]*` works with more shells than `.[^.]*` does.  The ksh flavors and dash seem to only accept ! for character class negation and not ^ - unless there is some way to properly quote the ^ for dash & ksh and get it working (but I didn't figure out a way to do that in some quick quoting / escaping attempts).  Maybe an edit to this answer that describes this would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Juan for all your useful comments. Answer corrected (finally!)

Answer (score 6):

The GNU version of find provides the builtin action -printf *format* which allows you to format the output of your query.

So to answer your question

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

Will output only the filenames with no leading characters (or pathnames) with a newline so each filename is on it's own line

Comment: the question was to eliminate leading "./" and not pathnames, but thanks for the trigger to read into find's printf capabilities. BTW: '%h/%f' does not help either.

Comment: @grenix Try: `find . -type f -printf '%P\n'`

Comment: From man page 
> %f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Answer (score 1):

The answers with `printf` are missing the point for the case where I want to run a command via `-exec` on the params and `echo` is just an example. In reality I may want to run `my-command` on the found files instead of `echo`

Here's a maybe not efficient but working solution:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo ${0#./}' "{}" \;
```

Explanation:

- We rely on the fact that `sh -c 'echo $0' foobar` runs a subshell which prints `$0`, and `foobar` is passed as `$0`, so it prints `foobar`
- instead of `$0`, we actually use `${0#./}`, which means "use `$0`, but strip leading `./` (`#./`) - this is [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)
- we pass `{}` from exec (the found filename from `find` with leading slash) as `$0` to `sh -c`

So in the end to run `my-command` on *found files without leading `./`*, you'd do:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'my-command ${0#./}' "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
find path/to/dir some/file other-file other/dir <criteria> -print
```

Or:

```
find path/to/dir some/file other-file other/dir <criteria> -exec cmd -- {} ';'
```

We tell `find` to find files matching the `<criterial>` starting with the list of file paths given as initial arguments.

If `path/to/dir` above matches the `<criteria>`, it will be printed or `cmd` will be called with `--` and `path/to/dir` as arguments. Same for `some/file` or `other/dir`.

If `path/to/dir` is a file of type *directory*, and `-prune` has not been called for it, then `find` will carry on processing files within it, with `path/to/dir/file-within` as the path being processed.

`.` in that regard is just like any other path.  It's a path to the current working directory, so if `.` matches the criteria, that will print `.`, and if the `file-within` also does, it will print `./file-within`.

As others have said, the GNU implementation of `find` has a `-printf` predicate which can be used in place of `-print` to print other attributes of the matching files than the file path. `-print` is the equivalent of `-printf '%p\n'`, but in place of `%p`, you can also use:

- `%f`: the file's name without any leading path component (the *basename* or *tail*)
- `%h`: the directory containing the file or `.` for /-less path (the  *dirname* or *head*).
- `%P`: the file path relative to the initial dir/file it was found under, or the empty string for that file itself.
- `%H`: the initial dir/file it was found under
- and many other metadata of the file.

So except for `/`-less files, `%p` is the same as `%h/%f` and except for the initial dir/file themselves, the same as `%H/%P`.

For example:

```
$ find path/to/dir other-file -printf '%%p="%p" %%h="%h" %%f="%f" %%H="%H" %%P="%P"\n'
%p="path/to/dir" %h="path/to" %f="dir" %H="path/to/dir" %P=""
%p="path/to/dir/file-within" %h="path/to/dir" %f="file-within" %H="path/to/dir" %P="file-within"
%p="other-file" %h="." %f="other-file" %H="other-file" %P=""
```

```
$ cd path/to/dir
$ find . -printf '%%p="%p" %%h="%h" %%f="%f" %%H="%H" %%P="%P"\n'
%p="." %h="." %f="." %H="." %P=""
%p="./file-within" %h="." %f="file-within" %H="." %P="file-within"
```

```
find . <criteria> -printf '%P\n'
```

Will report the paths of matching files relative to the current working directory but not for `.` itself, so in the general case, you rather need:

```
find . <criteria> '(' -name . -print -o -printf '%P\n' ')'
```

(`.` wouldn't match a `-type f` criteria though, so we do not need to special case it in that case or any other case where we can guarantee `.` won't match the criteria).

Now, assuming your `echo` was just an example standing in for any another command, `-printf` alone won't help.

With the GNU implementation of `xargs`, and a shell with ksh-style process substitution, you can do though:

```
xargs -0I {} -a <(
  find . <criterial> '(' -name . -print0 -o -printf '%P\0' ')'
) cmd -- {}
```

Where `find` prints those relative paths NUL-delimited, which `xargs` retrieves and passes as argument to `cmd`.

Or even:

```
xargs -r0 -a <(
  find . <criterial> '(' -name . -printf '.\0' -o -printf '%P\0' ')'
) cmd --
```

If `cmd` can take more than one file path as argument (similar to what you can do with `-exec cmd {} +`).

Now, that won't help if `-exec cmd {} ';'` was intended to be used as a *condition*, like in:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l needle {} ';' \
  -exec cmd-for-files-with-needle {} ';'
```

Where the `cmd-for-files-with-needle` is executed for files for which `grep` succeeds (after having printed the path of the matching files with `-l`).

Then, you could do instead (and that does not require GNU `find` nor `xargs`):

```
find . <criteria> -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    file=${file#./} # strip the leading ./ if any. It leaves . as is,
                    # so we do not need to special-case it
    grep -l -- needle "$file" && 
      cmd-for-files-with-needle -- "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

Note the need for `--`, now that the file paths are not guaranteed to start with `.` and therefore *may* start with `-`.

Or you could use zsh where globs can do most of what `find` can do. For instance:

```
for file in **/*(ND.m-1); do
  grep -l -- needle $file &&
    cmd-for-files-with-needle -- $file
done
```

Where the `.` [*glob qualifier*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) is the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`, `m-1` of `-mtime -1`, `N` for nullglob, `D` for dotglob.

Here, a `./` prefix is not included (you could do `./**/*` if you wanted it), `.` is not included (like `-mindepth 1` in GNU `find`), and the list is sorted (and the sorting order can be changed with the `o`/`O`/`n` glob qualifiers)